# Conditionally use operators (NOT talking about ?:)

Tags: c#

Since this is an awkwardly worked question, an answer might already exist, but I couldn't readily find one. So if one does exist, sorry in advance.

Given some condition, I want to change the operator used. For example, what I have now adds or removes function calls when events are fired, and is similar to,

```
private void Register(bool add)
{
    if(!add)
    {
        eventA += func1;
        ...
        eventZ += func26;
    }
    else
    {
        eventA -= func1;
        ...
        eventZ -= func26;
    }
}
```

Ideally, what I would like is something akin to,

```
private void Register(bool add)
{
    operator op = (!add ? += : -=);

    eventA op func1;
    ...
    eventZ op func26;
}
```

(Obviously is doesn't work this way, but hence the problem) Is it possible to conditionally change the the operator that is used?

Comment: My situation is more complex than what is given, the `-=` and `+=` were to make it more simple to explain, for people to read, and for people to give an answer.

Comment: In general? No. But there are many *specific* ways of doing this. Delegates, interfaces, math... you'll need to pick the best way given what you actually need to do.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There's no way to assign an operator to a name like this. While there is likely a cleaner solution to the problem, it depends on the exact problem's context.

Comment: You could defie your own `operator`-interface with a common method `Execute`. Then you have some classes implementing that interface, e.g. the `Add`-class that stands fr `+` and the `IsTrue`-class that is for `?`. Is this what you want?

Comment: As @ColonelThirtyTwo has stated, this is an XY Problem.  Your update hasn't really clarified the question.  You might want to try and identify what *problem* you are trying to solve and ask about that, instead about asking how to implement your *potential solution*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the "more exact situation", a simple lambda still seems like the simplest solution (though do make sure it isn't too expensive for your use case):

```
private void Register(bool add)
{
    Func<int, int, int> op = (add ? (a, b) => a + b : (a, b) => a - b);

    m_A = op(m_A, func1);
    ...
    m_Z = op(m_Z, func26);
}
```

(you might need some changes to the syntax, I can't verify the code right now; it might require some extra parentheses or explicit casts or something)

The assignment itself isn't easy to replace, since lambdas don't support reference arguments; there's no way to just do `op(ref m_A, func1)`, which would be the most useful for what you're trying to do. If you don't need those functions to be anonymous, you can simply use a helper method:

```
private static void applyOp(ref int a, int b, bool add)
{
  if (add) a += b; else a -= b;
}

private void Register(bool add)
{   
    applyOp(ref m_A, func1, add);
    ...
    applyOp(ref m_Z, func26, add);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most literal translation of your pseudocode into C# that I could think of would be to define a `delegate` with appropriate parameters.  For the `+=` and `-=` operations, using a `ref` parameter makes this possible, but you can define whatever types of parameters you need.

```
public delegate void Op(ref int evnt, int fnc);

private void Register(bool add)
{
    Op op = add
        ? new Op((ref int evnt, int fnc) => evnt += fnc)
        : new Op((ref int evnt, int fnc) => evnt -= fnc);

    op(ref eventA, func1);
    op(ref eventB, func2);
    ...
    op(ref eventZ, func26);
}
```

It should be noted that this particular example can be solved using straightforward math.

```
private void Register(bool add)
{
    int mult = add ? 1 : -1

    eventA += mult * func1;
    eventB += mult * func2;
    ...
    eventZ += mult * func26;
}
```

Comment: The linear equation hack was nice ;-)